# Wrong format of the data is being sent via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, django

This is how my data is going via ajax request. Is this is the right format?

Expected Format:

```
{
 "connection": 80,
 "trans_data": [
    {
      "name": conditional_transformation,
      "display_text": Conditional Transformation,
      "trans_text": statement,
      "trans_type": condition,
    }
  ]
}
```

The ajax code for the request is as follow as:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
  url : "url",
  type: "POST",
  data : transObj,
  dataType: "json",
  timeout: 600000,
})
```

**transObj** is the variable which gets its value assigned form the other API with few JavaScript operation.

Format that is being sent via browser

```
connection: 80
trans_data[0][name]: conditional_transformation
trans_data[0][display_name]: Conditional Transformation
trans_data[0][trans_text]:  statement
trans_data[0][trans_type]: condition
```

Because my back-end system is looking for the keyword `trans_data` which is a array of objects. But due to this structure the back-end is not able to process API.

Below is the console output:

```
{connection: "80", transformations_data: Array(1)}
connection: "80"
trans_data: Array(1)
0:
display_name: "Conditional Transformation"
name: "conditional_transformation"
trans_text: "statement"
trans_type: "condition"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object}
```

Comment: `Is this is the right format?`   I'm not sure how you would expect random people to know what format to some unknown back-end.

Comment: @Keith I have updated the question

Comment: We maybe need to see the code your using to send the data, it looks like you are sending `multipart/form-data`, but the back end is likely wanting JSON -> `application/json`

Comment: The expected format code that you provided will actually work. Just set it a variable like `var data = ` and just fill in the text as needed.

Comment: @Keith. The ajax code has been updated

Comment: If `transObj ` contains trans_data, what exactly does `transObj ` look like when its being passed?

Comment: It should look like the one in expected format. But in browser's network it shows the last format.

Comment: As default if an object is passed to jquery it uses formData, not JSON.  try -> `JSON.stringify(transObj)` for the data prop.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What does the format look like in the console when you `console.log(transObj);`?

Comment: Question has been updated with console.log output

Comment: @keith It worked. Thank you so much. Can you put this as answer so that I can accept that as answer